# How do I add another part to the end of this parse that produces a string?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is what I have:

```
  startDate: DateTime.parse(dateEvent.split(' ').reversed.join()),
  endDate: DateTime.parse(dateEvent.split(' ').reversed.join()),
```

dateEvent gives me the date selected in the format yyyyMMdd from the format dd MM yyyy.

I need to add the time to this in order to add it to the calendar. I receive this as timeHour and timeMinute which are individual numbers. example: 8:30am would come as 8 and 30, 8:30pm would come as 16 and 30.

The ideal result would be `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer given was close, but the result was much simpler. I needed to add the line:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Then I could write my dates as a dateFormat which resulted in a simpler outcome as it could all be tied together in a String recognisable by the Calander apps:

```
  startDate: dateFormat.parse("$dateEvent $timeHour:$timeMinute:00"),
  endDate: dateFormat.parse("$dateEvent $timeHour:$timeMinute:00"),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime _getDateTime(String date, int timeHour, int timeMinute) {
  final dateTime = DateTime.parse(date);
  final hour = timeHour == 12 ? 0 : timeHour;
  final minute = timeMinute;
  final time = TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
  return dateTime.add(time);
}

String _formatDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
  final dateFormat = DateFormat('yyyyMMdd HH:mm:00');
  return dateFormat.format(dateTime);
}

void main() {
  final date = '20230727';
  final timeHour = 8;
  final timeMinute = 30;
  final dateTime = _getDateTime(date, timeHour, timeMinute);
  final formattedDateTime = _formatDateTime(dateTime);
  print(formattedDateTime); // 20230727 08:30:00
}
```

This code will first parse the date string into a DateTime object. Then, it will create a TimeOfDay object with the specified hour and minute. Finally, it will add the time to the date and format the resulting DateTime object in the yyyyMMdd HH:mm:00 format.